# How to assign ports to directories and merge IP's

Tags: remote

I'm using a RPi3B to monitor and control a solar panel array. I'm using the port 80 for html but would like to use other ports. How do I assign a subdirectoy a port number? Do I modify Apache and/or the Rpi?
  An example: I run a daemon to collect measurements and deposit themn in a csv file on a daily basis. I want to keep access separate from a public webpage about the array.
   A second question: I'm running the RPi as an access point for remote SSH when the array is stored outdoors with the array. When I setup the AP I assigned an IP to the RPi. When I move the RPi indoors, and connect with a LAN cable, I have a different DHCP IP reservation that I use indoors.
    Could I use the same IP in both instances without adverse effects? I know SSH is on port 22 and html is on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two pretty much unrelated questions there, which you should really post separately.

First question:

Yes, you can run multiple web servers on multiple ports.  Apache configuration is stored in `/etc/apache2`.  You need to listen on another port (see `ports.conf`) and add another virtual host (see the file(s) in the `sites-enabled` directory).  You may be able to work it out by looking at the configuration you already have, and if not, look for Apache configuration tutorials such as [this one](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html).

Second question:

I can't think of any reason why you can't use the same IP address for the same device in this case, provided it's only ever connected to one at a time.